# Required MatInput in Angular Material does not appear invalid after page loading

Tags: angular, material-ui

Please, help me understand how `required` attribute works on matInput in Angular Material.

I've tried an example as below:

```html
<mat-form-field class="example-form-field">
      <mat-label>Clearable input</mat-label>
      <input matInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="value" required>
      <button *ngIf="value" matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" (click)="value=''">
        <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
      </button>
</mat-form-field>
```

I've seen that the field is marked as `invalid` and becomes red-bordered only after user interacts with it (e.g. focus and then blur).

Why Angular does this logic? And, how can I mark the field as invalid already after page loading without user interacting with it?

Answer (score 0):

> The Boolean required attribute, if present, indicates that the user
> must specify a value for the input before the owning form can be
> submitted.

Angular provides [Reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) approach to handling form inputs whose values change over time.

So you can manually mark a form field as invalid.

You need **Validating form input** : it is used to ensure that user input is complete and correct.

One solution is to use markAsTouched in your component after initializing a form on ngOnit cycle.

> A control is marked touched once the user has triggered a blur event
> on it.

Exemple :

```
import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';

ngOnInit() {

   this.addressForm = this.fb.group({
       name: ['', Validators.required ]
    });

  this.addressForm.controls['name'].markAsTouched();
}
```

And once that the field is marked touched on init, the framework will make the validation logic for you.